# How do I create an Asset account using polkadot JS with a reason other than Consumer?

Tags: assets, accountdata

So there are 4 reasons listed on `ExistenceReason` for an Asset account namely:

1. Consumer,
2. Sufficient,
3. DepositHeld,
4. DepositRefunded

Usually minting an asset would use the `Consumer` reason. I'd like to create one using the `DepositHeld` reason, how can I achieve that using PolkadotJS? Also, bonus question, why is `DepositRefunded` a reason for asset account existence?

Answer (score 1):

So there's a function called `touch()` in pallet assets which will allow you to reserve the deposit `AssetAccountDeposit` in the runtime config, with the reason of `DepositHeld(..)`.

For sufficient reason, the asset must be created with `is_sufficient` = true. Currently, I did not find polkadot-js to support setting this parameter during asset minting.